# Android local notification doesn't arrive every time

Tags: android, android-notifications, local, android-alarms, reminders

I want my user to set a time to receive a daily reminder from my app. In my ReminderActivity I create the PendingIntent and the Alarm Manager, and then in my Alarm Receiver class I create the notification inside onReceive(). I tried both the FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT and FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flags when creating the pending intent but still when I am testing the app and changing the reminder time then sometimes the notification doesn't arrive at all, or it arrives only when the app is running in the background and the screen is on. I would greatly appreciate any thought or ideas.

**ReminderActivity code:**

```
private void setNotification() {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, chosenHour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, chosenMinute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    //if user sets the alarm after their preferred time has already passed that day
    if(now.after(calendar)) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ReminderActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

}
```

**Alarm Receiver code:**

```
   @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bitmap largeLogo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ptwired_logo);

    //create local notification
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    //notificationIntent.putExtra("FromPTWired", true); //to track if user opens the app from the daily digest notification

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ptwired_logo)
            .setLargeIcon(largeLogo)
            .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText(REMINDER_TEXT)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .build();



     notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue of Doze mode, take a look in Android restriction:

> Doze restrictions
>
> The following restrictions apply to your apps while in Doze:
>
> Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow()) are deferred to the next maintenance window.
>
> If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
>
> Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

Comment: Thank you @motis10 But `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` doesn't ask for an "interval" value and I want the alarm to repeat every day at the same time.

Comment: Right. but you can set the alarm every setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(). For example the intent can call the service. and the service can do functionallity + set new alarm for next day.

Comment: Got you. The thing is that I'm not using a service. Only a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Great. so reschedule it in your onReceive()